# I need added automatic calculation for “AGE” attribute that need to be calculated in oracle

Tags: oracle

[image]

[image]

if i have “INSERT INTO” i need added automatic calculation for “AGE” attribute that need to be calculated
I've tried

```
create or replace TRIGGER AGE_CALC03 BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON EMPLOYEES
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
:new.AGE := SYSDATE - :new.BIRTH_DATE; 
END AGE_CALC03;”
```

Comment: I've tried
create or replace TRIGGER AGE_CALC02 BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON EMPLOYEES
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF INSERTING THEN
    SELECT AGE_CALC.nextval INTO :new.EMPLOYEE_ID FROM dual;
    SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP INTO :new.BIRTH_DATE FROM dual;
  END IF;
  :new.AGE := SYSDATE - :new.BIRTH_DATE;
END AGE_CALC02;

Comment: Please don't include code, data, or text using images - instead post them as formatted text. See [Stack Overflow Markdown Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Also, please **edit your question** and tell us what the problem with your trigger is. Thanks.

Comment: Incidentally - down in the "Messages - Log" window in the images you posted there's an error message. It might be important...

Comment: I do not care how to , in image It's just one way to try it. I was only interested when INSERT INTO "PROJECT_EMPLOYEES"."EMPLOYEES" AGE column will have added automatic for “AGE” attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Having an AGE column is a bad choice because it will become incorrect if the data in the row is not refreshed regularly.

However, I suspect this is a school assignment and you don't care about the design problems. OK - the reason your trigger isn't giving you a good value for AGE is that the calculation is simply wrong. You're subtracting one date from another, thinking that this will give you the difference in years. It does not - it gives you the difference in **DAYS**.

The correct calculation to use for `AGE` is `FLOOR(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, BIRTH_DATE) / 12)`. So your trigger should read:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AGE_CALC03
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON EMPLOYEES
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :new.AGE := FLOOR(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, :new.BIRTH_DATE) / 12); 
END AGE_CALC03;
```

But - back to the problems with an AGE column. A better way to obtain an employees age is to have a function to call which returns you a persons age based on their birth date. Something like the following:

```
FUNCTION COMPUTE_AGE(pinBirth_date IN DATE)
  RETURN NUMBER
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN FLOOR(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, pinBirth_date ) / 12)
END COMPUTE_AGE;
```

Then get rid of the AGE column on the EMPLOYEES table and call this function any time you need someone's age, which will then be correct at any given moment in time.

Comment: i try CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AGE_CALC03
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON EMPLOYEES
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :new.AGE := FLOOR(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, BIRTH_DATE) / 12); 
END AGE_CALC03;
is Error(2,3): PL/SQL: Statement ignored and Error(2,45): PLS-00201: identifier 'BIRTH_DATE' must be declared

Comment: I do not care how to calculate in image It's just one way to try it. I was only interested when INSERT INTO "PROJECT_EMPLOYEES"."EMPLOYEES" AGE column will have added automatic for “AGE” attribute

Comment: Should be `:new.BIRTH_DATE`.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle 12 and later, use a virtual column and a deterministic function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION calculate_age(
  birth_date DATE,
  now_date   DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE
) RETURN INTEGER DETERMINISTIC
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN FLOOR( MONTHS_BETWEEN( now_date, birth_date ) / 12 );
END;
/
```

and:

```sql
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES (
  EMPLOYEE_ID           VARCHAR2(5 BYTE)
                        CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEES__EMPLOYEE_ID__NN NOT NULL
                        CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEES__EMPLOYEE_ID__PK PRIMARY KEY,
  FIRST_NAME            VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  LAST_NAME             VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  IDENTIFICATION_NUMBER NUMBER(13,0),
  MANAGER_ID            VARCHAR2(5 BYTE)
                        CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEES__MANAGER_ID__FK REFERENCES EMPLOYEES ( EMPLOYEE_ID ),
  DEPARTMENT_ID         VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
  WORKING_STATUS        VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
  BIRTH_DATE            DATE,
  AGE                   INTEGER
                        GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( calculate_age( BIRTH_DATE ) ) VIRTUAL
);
```

Then if you insert some sample data:

```sql
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES ( EMPLOYEE_ID, BIRTH_DATE )
SELECT 'Alice', DATE '2000-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Bob',   DATE '1990-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Carol', DATE '1980-01-01' FROM DUAL;
```

and query the ages:

```sql
SELECT Employee_id, birth_date, age FROM employees;
```

You get the output:

> ```
> EMPLOYEE_ID | BIRTH_DATE          | AGE
> :---------- | :------------------ | --:
> Alice       | 2000-01-01 00:00:00 |  20
> Bob         | 1990-01-01 00:00:00 |  30
> Carol       | 1980-01-01 00:00:00 |  40
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f02103024e76ad5612a5642590d5d36a)*

Comment: @MT0: I saw what you did there...and I suspect that it will eventually cause a problem.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica The function itself is deterministic as you will always get the same output for the same pair of inputs. The default for the second argument is non-deterministic and it is theoretically possible that Oracle may tighten their syntax to prevent this but it is allowed for all current Oracle versions (12-19) that also support generated columns.

Comment: You could even get rid of the second argument and just use `SYSDATE` in the function ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fee0ed464c10355deb0e6f37095b3d13)) but even if the syntax allows you to say the function is `DETERMINISTIC` (as it will always return the same value if it is called at the same time), I'm not sure I would support that interpretation which is why I didn't use it.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you already have the birth_date column in your system, Why do you have Age column too. This is redundancy of data. Whenever you need to show age you can simply use your logic as `SYSDATE - BIRTH_DATE`.
2. If you strictly need to use AGE column in your table, You have to use TRIGGER as you are currently using. Are you having any issues in doing so?

Comment: CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES (
EMPLOYEE_ID VARCHAR2(5 BYTE) NOT NULL 
,FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) 
, LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) 
, IDENTIFICATION_NUMBER NUMBER(13, 0) 
, MANAGER_ID VARCHAR2(5 BYTE) 
, DEPARTMENT_ID VARCHAR2(1 BYTE) 
, WORKING_STATUS VARCHAR2(1 BYTE) 
, BIRTH_DATE DATE 
, AGE INTEGER DEFAULT SYSDATE - BIRTH_DATE
, CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEES_PK PRIMARY KEY
(
    EMPLOYEE_ID 
)
);

Comment: why is Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "BIRTH_DATE": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: @Nitiphoom_000, I just recalled, You cannot use another column in default clause. So i ahev updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I do not care how to calculate in image It's just one way to try it.
I was only interested when INSERT INTO "PROJECT_EMPLOYEES"."EMPLOYEES"
AGE column will have added automatic for “AGE” attribute.

Comment: Trigger seems the best option to fulfill your need.